# What is the best practice for connecting to a remote database in MonoTouch

Tags: sql-server, orm, ado.net, xamarin.ios

I am creating a iPad app using MonoTouch and I would like to save the data to a remote SQL Server database. I believe my choices are:

1. ADO.NET
2. Catnap - ORM

I would like to use something that in case I have no internet connection it will store it locally and when I get a connection it will sync automatically. But that is the best case. I am assuming that 100% of the time their will be a connection.

Answer (score 3):

Best practice would be to expose your data via a secured set of web services, not to expose it directly to the internet.

MT's ADO.NET implementation is [limited at present](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/system.data), and is mostly used for connecting to local SQLite dbs.